# Calculating uncertainty in a fitted model

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, error-analysis, data-analysis

I am working on a project that requires the measurement of the Verdet constant of a material by observing a phase shift in the cosine squared model provided by Malus's law. I have recorded the uncertainty in the measurement of the intensity and degree of rotation to be $\pm 1.5$% and $\pm 5'$ respectively. I have no idea how to incorporate that into the uncertainty given by the following model:

$I = I_ocos^{2}(\theta-\theta_o) +c$

Measuring the phase shift between two different curves is relatively simple, but I have no idea how to propagate uncertainty through this. Here is a picture of the graph if that would be helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This must be a more common experiment than I would have imagined. My own students are doing a similar experiment right now though the analysis differs a bit.

It might be best to talk to your TA or professor to gain an understanding of how they expect you to propagate the uncertainty. For my own students, I would ask them to have their chosen fitting algorithm return the uncertainty in the $\theta_0$ parameter for each curve.

It depends on how you're doing the fitting, but I think every fitting algorithm should have an option to at least return a covariance matrix. The square roots of the diagonals of the covariance matrix are the uncertainties in the fitted parameters.

After getting the parameters and their uncertainties from the fitting algorithm, I would then have them propagate their uncertainty using the usual method.

One last note, I would normally expect them to weight their y-values using their uncertainties while performing the fit but to ignore the uncertainty in the x-axis. For most fitting algorithms, getting them to take uncertainties in both $x$ and $y$ is nontrivial and so we ignore it (this is a second-year experiment for them).

Comment: After digging around on some data analysis software, this ended up being the exact same approach I took. After I did so, I received a reasonable result after directly weighing the fit based on the y-error, so thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the approximation $I(\alpha)=I_{0}(1-2\alpha^{2}+\alpha^{4})$ where $\cos\alpha=(1-\alpha^{2})$ using the small angle approximation - then squaring it - setting $\alpha=\theta-\theta_{0}$ - the phase shift. Then take the derivative $dI(\alpha)/d\alpha=I_{0}4(\alpha^{3}-\alpha).$ Since $\alpha$ is small, I would throw out the $\alpha^{3}$ term and ignore the negative sign (assuming an upper bound - all errors add), then $dI(\alpha)/I_{0}=4\alpha d\alpha$. Assuming the derivative is an approximation to the uncertainty $\Delta$ yields $\Delta I(\alpha)/I_{0}=4\alpha \Delta\alpha$.